# boto3 conflict with endpoint url and bucket causing error

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

The correct file url from S3:

https://video-sftp.s3.amazonaws.com/600.mp4

Now when attempt to generate presigned url with boto3 the file url is incorrect:

https://video-sftp.s3.amazonaws.com/video-sftp/600.mp4

the bucket name is being appended as directory?

```
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL='https://video-sftp.s3.amazonaws.com'
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME='us-east-1'
```

Here is code:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        session = boto3.session.Session()
        client = session.client(
            "s3",
            region_name=settings.AWS_S3_REGION_NAME,
            endpoint_url=settings.AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL,
            aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
        )

        url = client.generate_presigned_url(
            ClientMethod="put_object",
            Params={
                "Bucket": "video-sftp",
                "Key": f"{json.loads(request.body)['fileName']}",
            },
            ExpiresIn=300,
        )
        return JsonResponse({"url": url})
```

It appears to be looking for directory `video-sftp` in the bucket `video-sftp`?  How do i solve?

I've tried changing the endpoint url to `https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`, which results in 403 forbidden.  I have updated CORs policy to allow `PUT`.

Comment: Remove `endpoint_url=settings.AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL`. endpoint_url should generally only be set when using a non-AWS API like localstack or other s3 compatible service.